# The Fate of Arseface from the TV Series Preacher

Tags: preacher, preacher-2016

In season 1, episode 5, Arseface, aka Eugene and Jesse gets in a heated argument over the questionable use (abuse?) of Jesse's Power imbued to him by the hybrid angelic/demonic entity, [Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Preacher_characters#Genesis). By this time Jesse has used the Power of Command freely among his flock to help them through everyday ordeals as well as miraculously redeeming Eugene back into the communities graces. As a result, Jesse developed a Messiah complex and when confronted by Eugene, Jesse commanded him to, ***"Go to Hell!"***.

Eugene returns from Hell in season 1, episode 7...or so I thought he did. It turns out he's a manifestation of Jesse's guilty conscience or is he's a demon in the shape of Eugene? Apparently no one but Jesse sees him, and it seems that Eugene is so real to Jesse that he phones his father, Sheriff Root, and tells him that his son is back after missing for days. So, is this a symptom of Jesse having a psychotic breakdown, an Arse-doppleganger, or a Arse-ghost?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't correspond with the actual question. Please fix this.

Comment: @BCdotWEB http://comicvine.gamespot.com/arseface/4005-10531/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real answer here would be you will just have to keep watching the show for if/when the writers reveal whats going on.

ATM there are 4 distinct possibilities

one: the preacher is having a psychotic break

two: Genesis sent Eugene to hell physically where his body was promptly vaporized and when preacher used Genesis to bring Eugene back Genesis couldnt recreate the body so only Eugene's soul could return

three: some denizen of hell managed to claw its way out possibly through whatever breach was created when Eugene was sent in, it sensed preachers guilt and assumed the form in order to mess with him or feed from him in some way

four: the show writers are using the actor for Eugene to play the character of The Duke from the comics, in the comics The Duke was some form of guardian angel who would occasionally be used to advance the plot

Comment: Two is an interesting take I hadn't considered, and four as well (I have yet to read the comics, but will).